# Two paths for Win10 start shortcuts

Tags: windows-10, path, shortcuts, start-menu

Few of my shortcuts in Start suddenly disappeared. When I tried to discover why, I found that there are two paths for shortcuts in Start:

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

and

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

Why is that? Where I should eventually put my shortcuts manually (not via drag'n'drop in start) to show them in Start menu? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts (.LNK files) go in both locations depending if

(a) All users - first choice {Program Data) OR

(b) Per User - second location above in User folder.

Do not mix them up and allow the program installer to pick the correct location.

All are available in the Windows 10 Main Start menu.

Comment: Thanks. Not all are available. Few of them I need to create manually (ie specific setting menu that I use daily) so I'll put them in user folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get shortcuts on your Start Menu my putting them in

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

or

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Shortcuts must be outside of your Programs folders, right clicked on and "Pin to Start".

Learn [how to backup and restore the Windows 10 start menu](https://www.google.com/search?&q=windows%2010%20how%20to%20backup%20and%20restore%20start%20menu). It will come in handy.

Backup both Programs folders everyday so that you can right click on the backup and "Pin to Start".

Comment: "Shortcut" is generic language here for the LNK files contained in the start menu folders